# How to disable sort in a CdkDropList using angular cdk v7.0.0+

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I'm creating two CdkDropList objects and the dragging and dropping functionalities are working fine, my problem is that I would like to disable the sorting while I'm dragging in the first list. Let's say I have List A and List B. I'm dragging from A to B, I would like to disable the sorting while I'm over List A. In other words, I just want the drag n drop functionality, not the sorting. Can I disable that?

Comment: can you clarify your question please !

Comment: Usually when you are dragging the element is changing position in the list, is changing the index on the "parent" list. I want to be able to drag from one list to the other but without sorting the elements, I don't know how to explain that better

Comment: @LeslieMorejon did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: No @d.moncada, I haven't found a way

Comment: I have currently the same problem :(

Comment: @LeslieMorejon I am having the same issue. Do you have any updates on this?

Answer (score 5):

It's implemented now in the drag & drop module of Angular Material 8 > see [Disabled sorting](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#disabled-sorting)

Answer (score 2):

I can do it simply adding a css property to the draggable div. I don't know that is the best solution, but, this work for me:

html:

```
<div cdkDropList>
    <div class="item-draggable" *ngFor="let item of items" cdkDrag>
        <span>{{item.label}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.item-draggable {
  transform: none !important;
}
```

**UPDATE 10/28/2020**

Angular material implemnt this with @Input sortingDisabled -> https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api

Answer (score 1):

Super easy **WORKAROUND**... split up ListA into a new cdkDropList for each item of ListA.

***List A***

```
<div class="list-A-wrapper">
    <ng-container  *ngFor="let item of listA">
      <div  cdkDropList
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['id_listB']"
            [cdkDropListData]="[item]">

            <div cdkDrag>{{item.label}}</div>

      </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

***List B***

```
<div  cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="listB"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="OnDrop($event)"
      id="id_listB">
  <div  *ngFor="let item of listB"
        cdkDrag>{{item.label}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code to stop sorting

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items;">        
      <div style="position: absolute; width:100%;height: 100%" cdkDrag>
        <p *cdkDragPreview>{{item}}</p>
      </div>
      <p>{{item}}
      </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As some other answers mention, you can now apply the `[cdkDropListSortingDisabled]` property on the `CdkDropList` element to disable sorting within the list. Here's an example of what it would look like:

```
<div cdkDropList cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true">
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try setting the `cdkDropListLockAxis` input to `'x'` on the container you don't want to sort, in your case the first list. This will prevent the draggable item from moving up and down the list.

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListLockAxis]="'x'">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items" cdkDrag>
        <span>{{item.label}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Check the Angular CDK Drag and Drop documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api)

Comment: I think that's not a "solution"

Comment: This still starts to flicker in the origin list sometimes